# How to get Android emulator to rotate its window

Tags: android-emulator

The new Android emulator installed with Android Studio Bumblebee has two buttons in its toolbar to rotate the emulated device 90 degrees clockwise or anticlockwise. On the old emulator rotating the device would rotate the emulator's window as well, but on the new one it doesn't.

So if you start the emulator in portrait mode and rotate you get a tiny landscape device image stuck across the middle of the emulator's portrait window, and if you start the emulator in landscape mode and rotate you get a tiny portrait device image stuck up the middle of the emulator's landscape window.

Is there any way to recreate the old behaviour where pressing the rotate buttons would rotate the emulator's window to fit the rotated phone image inside it?

[Running on Linux with kde window system, in case it make any difference]

Answer (score 1):

I think to recreate old behavior with regards to separate emulator window and rotation you may want do the following:

**1.** Disable the docking and may be open in Window mode to keep emulator window separate from the main IDE as shown below

[image]

**2.** To rotate, Virtual sensors option can be utilized as follows. Steps are marked 1,2,3 & 4. Beware seems the button marked 4 only appears for few seconds.

[image]

Also, one can horizontally expand the emulator window pane when device is in landscape position, to get a feel of landscape window like below:

[image]

Following blog post can also be helpful in this regard:

https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2020/10/android-studio-41.html

In case important e.g. if options do not appear the same, i'm using Moonlight(Material) theme

Comment: This seems to have been fixed in the latest version (Android Studio Bumblebee 2021.1.1 Patch 3), at least if you run the emulator in a standalone window: this can be configured in File->Settings->Tools->Emulator.